# Cypress intermittently calls real window.alert() despite stubbing it

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress 8.7.0 to test my component written in Angular 13. And the following code is how I stub `window.alert` which will be called by the component when something has failed.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.window().then((win) => {
    cy.stub(win, 'alert').as('windowAlert');
  }).then(() => {
    // Some code here to setup my subject under test
    // to ensure that stubbing of window.alert happens first
    // before anything else.
  });
});
```

Maybe 60% of the time, it works fine and Cypress doesn't show real alert prompt when my test case is running. Here's an example of Cypress calling the real `window.alert()` despite being stubbed.

[image]

And here's the evidence that `window.alert()` is really stubbed when that happens.

[image]

I have tried isolating the problem and creating a simpler example I just couldn't reproduce the issue and I don't know where else could be the problem. It seems sometimes Cypress fails to stub `window.alert()`.

Here's screenshot of debugger when Cypress fails to stub `window.alert()` and shows real alert prompt (not expected behavior).

[image]

Here's screenshot of debugger when Cypress successfully stubs `window.alert()` and doesn't show real alert prompt (expected behavior).

[image]

This looks like to me that either Zone.js modifies `window.alert()` or Cypress does it. It looks like a race condition to me.

**The Problem**

Cypress fails to stub `window.alert()` and calls real `window.alert()` which causes the test case to be stuck until the alert prompt window is dismissed manually. No issues with the assertions.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like (from the log) you are using `cy.get('@windowAlert')` to test if the alert has been called.

The problem is `cy.get()` is not waiting for the event, it's just getting the alias and testing whatever it has at that point in time.

Ideally, you want `cy.wait('@windowAlert')` as with intercepts, but that doesn't work with stubs.

I used a minimal page to try to reproduce, from [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert) but with added `setTimeout()` in case your problem is caused by some delay in the app (maybe a fetch occurs before the alert).

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert('I am an alert box!')     // async call after 4 seconds
        }, 00)                         
      }
    </script>40
  </body>
</html>
```

If I use the Cypress example [Assert on the alert text](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Window-Alert), it works without the `setTimeout()` but fails at around 100ms delay.

Changing the example from `.then()` to `.should()` adds retry in to the mix, and the test now works for delays up to 4 seconds.

This is the test

```js
it('can assert on the alert text content', () => {

  const stub = cy.stub()

  cy.on('window:alert', stub)

  cy.get('button')
    .click()
    .should(() => {
      expect(stub.getCall(0)).to.be.calledWith('I am an alert box!')
    })
})
```

If you want to handle longer delays, there is nowhere to add extended timeout to commands to achieve that, but you can set the extended timeout in the test header.

This will work for up to 10 seconds delay:

```js
it('can assert on the alert text content', {'defaultCommandTimeout': 10_000}, () => {
```

Comment: My test case actually succeeds when I manually click on the window alert prompt. My real issue is that the real alert prompt shows up when it shouldn't because it will get stuck forever if test case runs headless on a CI/CD. The problem is not the assertion and calling `cy.get()`, the problem is Cypress fails to stub the window.alert().

Comment: I have updated the question to add more details.

Comment: `cy.stub()` is a wrapper around Sinon stub. Yes Cypress internally stubs the alert in order to stop it showing and automatically accepting it at the same time, which is why I suggest following their documented example of  trapping the `cy.on('window:alert')` event. Your way of stubbing fails in a plain HTML page, so it's doubtful you can get it working in Angular.

Comment: I tried your example using `cy.on(..)` now it calls the real window.alert 100% of the time.

Comment: I've also tried `cy.on()` on a simpler project, it does not work too. `cy.window()` is the only approach that works for me but inconsistently. Perhaps yours is not supported on version 8.7.0 that I'm using?

Comment: Nope, it works fine on version 8.70 of Cypress. I've no idea what your simple example does, but the key thing you should be doing is making sure there's retry in the test code - e.g `.should(() => expect()...`. That's a key thing Cypress does, uses retry to avoid flaky tests.